# how to make jQuery intellisense plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to implement jQuery intellisense. Can any one provide me any good link or tutorial for this or any hint that how can i implement it.
Thanks

Comment: What you want is not clear. Do you want to implement some intellisense like feature in the browser (like in a textarea?) or do you want to get jQuery intellisense in your IDE?

Comment: he wants to make a plugin for intellisense

Comment: intellisense feature in the browser (like in a textarea?). Here you can see this [link]http://www.alibaba.com/.  when you open the page there is a text field with **Search Products** written in it. I want to implement that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which is part of the jQuery UI plugin.

Comment: @Basit, not necessarily, no, but it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the difference between autocomplete and intellisense? Both look same? Why one is called autocomplete and one is intellisense? Thanks

Comment: @Basit I don't know where you got the intellisense part from. The website you linked shows autocomplete on the search form. Intellisense is a feature in Microsoft IDEs for code completion based on context. It is far more complex than autocomplete and serves a different purpose.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Actually client asked our manager that he wants intellisense. The feature that alibaba site is using(the link that i posted). I saw the site and told our manager that it is autocomplete. But he said, no, it is intellisense. To be very frank i don't know what is intellesense. I concluded from the name it is just intelli(intelligent)- sense(search). Now you confirmed me that it is just autocomplete now i am relax :). But one thing that i want to ask. When i type a in the autocomplete box then it shows me all the names, i want just the names that start from a.

Comment: One thing more. What i understood is that intelliesense is a feature that IDEs offer.  is it? And it is based on context? You can't offer intellisense on websites, like in a text field. is it? In text fields there is just autocomplete?

Comment: @Basit you're the one who gives the plugin the words it autocompletes with. In your case, you could only give it words that start with "a". And yes, intellisense is actually a trademarked name for a feature in Microsoft Visual Studio that use code context to make suggestions. It is a LOT more complex than autocomplete and used in a coding environment.